# a question about quota sampling method

Tags: survey-sampling

Currently I'm designing a online survey experiment. I chose quota sampling method to secure representative sample.

However, I got to come up with a question: Is it okay to just send online survey to people, and then filter collected answer randomly by sampling criteria and then discard response from filtered participants? Or should I filter participants first by sampling criteria and then collect response and calculate the response rate etc?

This question may seem a little trivial, but I failed to find an appropriate answer. Please help.

Comment: if you want to do probabilistic sampling, then you shouldn't discard units by deterministic criteria. If you can, it would be better to stratify your population first and draw a stratify sampling with proportional allocation.